# Quiz Timer JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Would anyone be able to check this code and see where I'm going wrong. The quiz should give you 1 minute to answer the questions. If the user completes the quiz in time, it should display the reset button and stop the timer. If the user then clicks the reset button, the quiz should restart with a restarted timer.

If the timer runs out, the quiz displays the reset button.

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn')
const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn')
const questionContainerElement = document.getElementById('question-container')
const questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
const answerButtonsElement = document.getElementById('answer-buttons')

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex

var timeInMinutes = 1;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    clock.innerHTML = t.minutes + ':' + t.seconds;
    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
      startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    }
  }
  
  updateClock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  currentQuestionIndex++
  setNextQuestion()
})

function startGame() {
  currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
  deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);
  console.log(new Date, deadline) 
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
  startButton.classList.add('hide')
  shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
  currentQuestionIndex = 0
  questionContainerElement.classList.remove('hide')
  setNextQuestion()
}

function setNextQuestion() {
  resetState()
  showQuestion(shuffledQuestions[currentQuestionIndex])
}

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}

function resetState() {
  clearStatusClass(document.body)
  nextButton.classList.add('hide')
  while (answerButtonsElement.firstChild) {
    answerButtonsElement.removeChild(answerButtonsElement.firstChild)
  }
}

function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
  }
}

function setStatusClass(element, correct) {
  clearStatusClass(element)
  if (correct) {
    element.classList.add('correct')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('wrong')
  }
}

function clearStatusClass(element) {
  element.classList.remove('correct')
  element.classList.remove('wrong')
}

const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is 2 + 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '4', correct: true },
      { text: '22', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Who is the best YouTuber?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Web Dev Simplified', correct: true },
      { text: 'Traversy Media', correct: true },
      { text: 'Dev Ed', correct: true },
      { text: 'Fun Fun Function', correct: true }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'Is web development fun?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Kinda', correct: false },
      { text: 'YES!!!', correct: true },
      { text: 'Um no', correct: false },
      { text: 'IDK', correct: false }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is 4 * 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '6', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: true }
    ]
  }
]
```

```css
*, * ::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    --hue-neutral: 200;
    --hue-wrong: 0;
    --hue-correct: 145;
}

body{
font-size: 2rem;
--hue: var(--hue-neutral);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 20%);
}


body.correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
}

body.wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}

.container{
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

.btn-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
    gap: 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.btn{
    font-size: 2rem;
    --hue: var(--hue-neutral);
    border: 1px solid hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 30%);
    background-color: hsl(var(--hue), 100%, 50%);
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
}

.btn:hover{
    border-color: black;
}

.btn-correct {
    --hue: var(--hue-correct);
    color: black;
}

.btn-wrong {
    --hue: var(--hue-wrong);
}

.start-btn, .next-btn{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.score-btn{
    background-color: coral;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.controls{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.titlecontainer{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

#time{
    color: red;
    justify-content: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="clockdiv"></div>
    <div id="question-container" class="hide">
      <div id="question">Question</div>
      <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
      <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Java !== JavaScript && this === JavaScript; pleaseTryToBeMoreSpecificAboutTheErrorYoureExperiencing()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, the problem is that countdown does not stop when quiz is finished. Countdown works thanks to this line in the function initializeClock

`var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);`

So all you should do is to kill this process with

`clearInterval(timeinterval)`

when the quiz is over. But here is the problem - you can not reach varyable 'timeinterval' from outside of initializeClock function. The easiest way to solve this is:

1. Declare 'timeinterval' in the global scope.
2. Make some changes inside selectAnswer function just like this:

```
function selectAnswer(e) {
  const selectedButton = e.target
  const correct = selectedButton.dataset.correct
  setStatusClass(document.body, correct)
  Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
    setStatusClass(button, button.dataset.correct)
  })
  if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
    nextButton.classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    // THESE ARE THE OLD 'ELSE' INSTRUCTIONS:
        // startButton.innerText = 'Restart'
    // startButton.classList.remove('hide') 

    // HERE BELOW ARE NEW:
    clearInterval(timeinterval) // clear current countdown
    startButton.innerText = 'You finished, restart?'// Little text mod
    startButton.classList.remove('hide') //this is exactly from old version
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I’ll give it a go.